# Barra que muda de tempo em tempo

Tags: javascript, html

Galera, tenho uma barrinha aqui no meu site

```
<div style="padding: 30px;" class="bg-light-gray" id="barra- programas"></div>
```

Eu quero usar JS para fazer com que a cada 10 segundos ela mude de texto, no

```
/sistemas/frases.php
```

Quando acessa ele vem com uma frase diferente, a cada 10 segundos eu quero que o js pegue uma frase de lá e coloque ela na barrinha, eliminando a mensagem anterior.

Comment: Como vais buscar esse texto ao PHP? Carregas a página já com o texto/array de palavras numa variável ou queres usar ajax?

Comment: Quero um setTimeout a cada 10 segundos, cada 10 segundos vai passando, daí ele acessa um texto de uma aray e coloca o texto lá.

Comment: Esse texto do php vai ser dinâmico? vai pegar do banco de dados? se não por que não colocar direto no js

Comment: Não, se quiser pode ser numa array no JS mesmo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```js
var bar = ['texto 1', 'texto 2', 'texto 3'];
var start = 0;

function foo() {
  if (start == bar.length) {
    start = 0;
  }
  document.getElementById('qux').innerHTML = bar[start];
  start++;
}

setInterval(foo, 1000);
```

```css
#qux {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="qux"></div>
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou!!!!!

Comment: Tenta dar uma olhada na lógica para ver se você entendeu, se não entender alguma parte me pergunta!

Comment: Amigo, tem como fazer um fade pra passar de texto??